# sum values with case insensitive join not grouping correctly

Tags: postgresql, join, group-by

I have two tables I want to join in a case insensitive way. Thanks to other topics on SO this is working using lower(). However, the result is not grouped by the lower case values but still appears to be case sensitive. How do I adjust the query so that the grouping is case insensitive?

Example data:
Table 1 (only using 1 column right now of this table, there is more metadata though ;):

```
keyword
TEST
ABC
ASF
QWERTY
```

Table 2:

```
Date - term - value
2020-01-01 - test - 3
2020-01-01 - Test - 2
2020-01-03 - TEST - 4
2020-01-01 - abc - 6
2020-01-02 - ABC - 7
2020-01-02 - abc - 3
```

Desired output:

```
keyword - sum(value)
test - 9
abc - 16
```

Current output:

```
keyword - sum(value)
test - 3
test - 2
test - 4
abc - 9
abc - 7
```

Query I'm using:

```
select distinct lower(keyword), value
FROM Table1 t1
join (select lower(term) term, sum(value) value from Table2 group by term) t2 on lower(t1.keyword) = lower(t2.term) 
GROUP BY t2.term, t1.keyword, t2.value
```

It seems all the output needs is (another) group by, but whether I group or not it doesn't change the result. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple option here would be to just lowercase both sides of the join condition:

```
SELECT
    t1.keyword,
    SUM(t2.value) AS total
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON LOWER(t1.keyword) = LOWER(t2.term)
GROUP BY
    t1.keyword;
```

Note that using `LOWER` in multiple places of the join probably means that your query would not be able to use any index.  For best performance, consider storing your keyword/term data in the same case everywhere.

Comment: this is giving me wrong sums, most likely because of the product of the join? That's how I ended up using the distinct and subquery

Comment: No...if the keywords in the first table are either primary keys or unique, then my query should be working for you.  Maybe add more realistic sample data if I could be missing something here.

Comment: you are correct... something went wrong in de-duplication of the values. Fixed it and your query works as expected

Answer (score 0):

Use `lower()` in `GROUP BY` too, if you want to group by the lowered value. Also you query can be simplified. There's no need for the derived table or `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT lower(t1.keyword),
       sum(t2.value) value
       FROM table1 t1
            INNER JOIN table2 t2
                       ON lower(t1.keyword) = lower(t2.term)
       GROUP BY lower(t1.keyword);
```